# SQL Server Connection String in Trusted Connection format doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms, connection-string, sql-server-2019

first time using sql with C# and I seem to be running into an unbreakable wall. I'm trying to connect to my database which is on a different server on the same domain. This is all within a winform app. Also the windows account I am using for running this winform application has read and write permissions to the sql database already (Same domain account). I've set my connection string in my app.config as follows following the advice from connectionstrings.com

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="my_db" connectionString="Server=10.xx.xx.xx;Database=my_db;Trusted_Connection=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I have the following method in Helper.cs where I am setting the Connection string from the config file.

```
public static string CnnVal(string name)
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[name].ConnectionString;
    }
```

Lastly, I have the following method in its own class, DbConnect.cs, and this method is called when I click a button on a form.

```
public void TestConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Helper.CnnVal("my_db")))
            {
                var query = "Select 1";
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Executing {query}");

                var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"successful connection");

                command.ExecuteScalar();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Successful query");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"failure {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
```

I set breakpoints on "var command" and "command.ExecuteScalar();" lines and when looking at my Watch tab in visual studio, I can see that my connection is not opened and this leads to an InvalidOperationException from SqlCommand. I'm not sure why this is happening. I used sql server migration assistant this morning to migrate the server from mysql over to sql and my info all worked then (windows auth, ip, database name). What could the outlier be here? Do I have to put the port number in my connection string somewhere? I'm using the default 1433 port. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Open your connection explicitly,using `connection.Open()`, before calling ExecuteScalar().

Comment: Also you have a connectionstrings named _my_db_  but you pass _pqual_db_

Comment: On another note, you should be `disposing` the `SqlCommand` when you are done with it.

Comment: @Steve Yea error on my part. That's the actual name of the name in appconfig, I had just edited for the question's sake

Comment: Just because you create an SqlConnection doesn't mean that it is automatically opened. You need to call _connection.Open()_ before using any SqlCommand